# Uploading changed Drupal content from production to server

Tags: nodes, migrations

I haven't yet setup version control (GIT) for my development and production environments as a result I am facing trouble syncing everything. My site is powered by Drupal 7.

For example, for a Content type that I created, what exactly is the folder on my development site that I should be uploading. And as far as the content type I created, what folder should I be uploading to the live server?

Another case is where I make changes to 'Text formats' found in admin -> configuration and a couple of other places in admin -> configuration, well, Not sure what folder I should be uploading either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Backup and Migrate" module or "Features" Module to upload your content to the production server.

Answer (score 1):

GIT will not be helpfull in this case. To transfer a contenet type from one Drupal installation to an other one you can either export and import it or use the features module (with features GIT could be handy).

For the other configuration changes you might be succesfull with the strongarm module. But for small configuration changes it's often more convenient to take some notes and just redo them on production.